# Хранение больших изображений в базе

Tags: изображения, mysql

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ увеличить максимальный размер *blob*-данных, хранящихся в *MySql* без редактирования параметров сервера?

Спрашиваю, потому что *shared*-хостинг, менять настойки *MySql* не могу.

Comment: Тут где-то задавался вопрос про хранение фоток в БД, и там порекомендовали хранить фото где-нибудь на диске, а в таблице только путь до них. В этом случае Ваш вопрос уже не будет актуальным

Comment: Мне нужно именно в бд. Заливать фотки буду не я и никто не станет прописывать пути до фоток. Им проще залить в бд и все. Придется видимо брать VPS-сервер.

Comment: А если заливать через какую нибудь веб морду или приложение, которое само определит куда пихать и путь до них в базу.

Comment: @IVsevolod, Ну это да, мысль.

Comment: Вам обязательно нужен MySQL для этого? GridFS в mongodb отлично для этого подходит.

Answer (score 2):

В MySQL четыре типа `BLOB` со следующими максимальными размерами:

- `TINYBLOB` - 255 байт
- `BLOB` - 64 Кб
- `MEDUIMBLOB` - 16 Мб
- `BIGBLOB` - 4 Гб

Поэтому если изменить тип с `BLOB` на `MEDUIMBLOB` или вообще на `BIGBLOB` вы можете сохранить почти любой файл. Однако, это крайне настоятельно не рекомендуется делать. Файлы тяжело и класть и извлекать из базы данных, остальные запросы к базе данных могут сильно затормаживаться, особенно, если вы используете InnoDB с хранением в едином табличном пространстве. Лучше хранить в таблицах лишь путь к файлам, а сами файлы хранить на жестком диске или в каком-либо специализированном файловом хранилище - такая схема масштабируется много проще.